# Apparent contradiction between the theory of hyperfunctions and the table of Fourier transforms

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

[Graf's book on hyperfunction theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034604079) says (page $36$) that

$$\frac1{(x-i0)^n}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\pi i}{(n-1)!}\delta^{(n-1)}(x)+\operatorname{fp}\frac1{x^n},$$

while the table of Fourier transforms says that the Fourier transform of $x^n$ is $2\pi i^n\delta^{(n)}(x)$.

The apparent contradiction is in the factorial factor $n!$
Based on the second formula the first one should be

$$\frac1{(x-i0)^n}=(-1)^{n-1}n\pi i\delta^{(n-1)}(x)+\operatorname{fp}\frac1{x^n}$$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: @Noah Schweber the one by Urs Graf, page 36

Comment: @Noah Schweber yes

Comment: I've edited to incorporated the citation.

Comment: Your formula for the Fourier transform of $x^n$ needs parentheses: $(2\pi i)^n\delta^{(n)}$. The cited formula from Graf seems correct to me. What did you do to get the alternative? That is, how did you use the Fourier transform?

Comment: @paul garrett Wikipedia gives that formula with no parentheses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: @Anixx, it's unfortunate that wiki has it messed up. But with $\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\,f(x)\;dx$, the parentheses are definitely needed. There are other possible normalizations, but none of the usual ones would have just a single $2\pi$, as opposed to $(2\pi)^n$.

Comment: Anyway, that wouldn't affect the factorial's absence or presence. What chain of computation seems to give the outcome without the factorial?

Comment: @paul garrett i feel bad just now, sorry...

Comment: @Anixx, ah, don't worry... :)

Comment: Dont trust the wiki for anything. Please dont ever cite it either.  It might be a good jumping off point for basic intro level stuff, but it should never be a basis for any education. Please do look to the external links and citations, etc.

Comment: Are you referring to rule 308 and the "non-unitary, angular frequency" column? Then there should not be any parentheses around $2\pi$. The formula on Wikipedia is correct. The "unitary, ordinary frequency" column, where parentheses are needed already has parentheses.

Comment: @paul garrett it seems my confusion came from using the following formula: $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_1^\infty 1/x^2 f(1/x)dx$ which seems not to work in divergent case.